# What is wrong with my code? (selecting all from DB not working)

Tags: php, mysql

Long time that i dont program php.

i made a function for the  cliente profile,so the cliente can see his logo

this is the cliente code

```
function display_logo(){
    global $conn;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT LogoImage FROM usuarios WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $em);
    $em = $_SESSION['useremail'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $img =$rows['LogoImage']; 
    echo '<img style="    margin-top: -14;
    object-fit: contain;" src="includes/file?file=' . $img. '"  />';

}
```

This code works fine for the  cliente profile.
But  now i am trying to display all users in my admin painel.

This way ...

```
function display_all_logo(){
    global $conn;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * LogoImage FROM usuarios");

    // $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  LogoImage FROM usuarios WHERE nome=?");
    // $stmt->bind_param("s", $em);
    // $em = $_SESSION['userName'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($LogoImage);

     while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["LogoImage"] = $LogoImage;


        array_push($LogoImage, $tmp);
    }

    $img =$rows['LogoImage']; 


echo '<img style="    margin-top: -14;
object-fit: contain;" src="includes/file?file=' . $img. '"  />';

}
```

i know that i'm doing something wrong, please someone help, long time that i don't program php.

**Fixed**

```
function display_all_logo($user_logo){
    global $conn;

     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT LogoImage FROM usuarios WHERE  logoImage = ?  ");


    $stmt->bind_param("s", $em);
    $em = $user_logo;
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $img =$rows['LogoImage']; 


return '<img style="    margin-top: -14;
object-fit: contain;" src="includes/file?file=' . $img. '"  />';

}
```

Comment: `SELECT * LogoImage FROM usuarios` I imagine should be `SELECT * FROM usuarios`

Comment: SELECT LogoImage FROM usuarios ....

Comment: This is why they made [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) for cases like this; you should use it.

Answer (score 2):

Your should select the column name

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT LogoImage FROM usuarios");
```

Comment: Yes that's right! I miss that for a bit

Comment: In or .. 2nd one is wrong ..

Comment: For the "or"; selecting all columns when only one is required, isn't needed and it's also bad practice. Plus, if their column count doesn't match, the `bind_result` will fail.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   correct  .. answer  updated .. thanks  ..

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_all_logo(){
    global $conn;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT LogoImage FROM usuarios");
```